# ERROR ITMS-90032:“Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':AppIcon 129x29”

Tags: xcode

`ERROR` ITMS-90032:“Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':AppIcon 129x29”

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8/xCode 6 answer, if you get an error AppIcon 120x120 not found, uncheck the car play icon in xcode's AppIcon set. Assuming you're not using car play of course

OR

Make sure that this image is a members of target you are building:

[image]

Also be aware that names are case sensitive.

1. Click on the affected image in the Project Navigator
2. In the utilities window, click the "Show the File Inspector" icon.
3. Ensure the "Target Membership" app name is selected.
4. Rebuild and archive.